# OFBiz and UNIX headeaches

Tags: windows, unix, installation, ofbiz

I have a few questions and that I want to ask they may sound a bit stupid but please give me few answers:

1. Is it possible to install ofbiz on a not-dedicated web hosting and what will it require and.
2. Is it a good idea to host it on a server "in the office".
3. Can you give me tips on how to access a UNIX server (cant be more specific cuz I don't know what UNIX exactly is it) using windows(I have the root password)?

P.S I know these sound nooby but.. excuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You can install ofbiz on any system, where you can run tomcat.

2- It depends on how you want to use it. If you are going to access it only from the office network, then I recommend it to be on a machine in the office. If you need to access it from outside then this is not going to work, unless you host another instance and synchronize them.

3- If you are going to host it on UNIX/Linux, then you need some skills to be able to perform the tasks successfully (At least if you need a production Database).

If I were you, I would do more reading on the topic before going any further. Here's the link to the documentation [Ofbiz Documenation](http://ofbiz.apache.org/documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

3) To access a remote UNIX server, you probably will use SSH protocol. On Windows [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is the most popular SSH client.